# You do not have permission to view this directory or page azure app service with nodeJs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Azure app service failed suddenly. My nodeJs app was deployed through azure app service. It was working perfectly fine, suddenly got failed by giving below error: and in the error log it was throwing module not found for different packages every time.
[image]

Then we flush out all the files from app service and did a fresh deployment, which is throwing below error now:
[image]
Anyone faced similar kind of issue, please help here.

Comment: Could you please share your Code Repo ?

Answer (score 0):

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

This happens due to various reasons like if there is any missing file in the deployed application or any modifications in configurations.

I was getting the same error when I tried to deploy my web application to Azure App Service. I figured out that, the application wasn't deployed properly and re-deployed the application, it worked as expected.

***Check if the below troubleshooting steps help to fix the issue:***

To know what causing the issue or error details, Enable logging in Azure App service->App Service logs as shown below:

[image]

- Also, check and validate web.config file and your YAML file.
- Check if the default document has been added in App Service to access the application:

[image]

- Add `\site\wwwroot\build` as physical path in *virtual applications and directories* in *path mappings*:
  [image]
- Check the IP restrictions or authentication settings on the Azure web application which could be blocking you from accessing the application.

If none of these steps work, try deploying the Nodejs application directly from vscode to App Service and check if you are facing the issue.

Comment: Just want to add to this, that Angular 17, by default, creates the `browser` folder and places inside it the files that would normally get created in the root `dist` folder.
Thus, you need to specify the path to your `index.html` file. That means the new Physical Path would be `site\wwwroot\browser`